# $(\mathcal L(X,Y),\|\cdot \|)$ is complete if $Y$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

In the proof, I get:

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb N: \forall n\geq N,\forall x\in X, \|(\hat T-T_n)x\|\leq \varepsilon\|x\|$$

where $\hat T$ is such that $T_nx\to \hat Tx$ for all $x\in X$. Then it's said that
we have proved that for all $n\geq N$, $\hat T=(\hat T-T_n)+ T_n$ is bounded and thus,
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb N: \|\hat T-T_n\|\leq \varepsilon.$$

I just don't understand this last implication.

Comment: The inverse is also true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last implication directly stems from : $\forall n\geq N : \forall x\in X, x\neq0,\frac{\|(\hat T-T_n)x\|}{\|x\|}\leq \varepsilon$

Taking the supremum for all $x\neq0$, we get by definition : $\|\hat T-T_n\|\leq \varepsilon.$

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity I denote $\hat{T}$ by $T$.

Let $T_n$ be Cauchy. We defined $T$ to be the map $x \mapsto y$ where $T_n x \to y$. I will assume you already showed that $T$ is linear and bounded so the only remaining thing to verify is that $\|T-T_n\|\to 0$:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $N$ such that $n,m \ge N$ implies $\|T_n-T_m\|\le \varepsilon$. Since this inequality holds for all $n > N$ it holds for the limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\|T_n -T_m\| = \|T-T_m\|\le \varepsilon$$

Hence $N$ is such that for $m \ge N$ we have $\|T-T_m\|\le \varepsilon$ which means that $\|T-T_m\|\to 0$ as desired.